# Ruby Rails, Get duplicate count for a column in db in the index erb page

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, duplicates

i've a little application in ruby rails.
I'm new on the language and i want to found on my database (mysql) the duplicate record in a specific column of my tables.

```
      <th>Count Activation</th>
<td align="center" width="4%"><%= Database.select(:license_code).count %></td>
```

I put that, and this get the column license_code and count how much times is present the record for the license code in the my application.

I need to found the duplicate value for the license_code, and the duplicate count for every values found and put into the column "count activation" of my erb page (is just a page showing the database:

```
<table width="120%" align="center" border="2" class="display" id="mytable" style="margin:3px">

<thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Negozio</th>
      <th>Cliente</th>
      <th>Azienda</th>
      <th>Referente</th>
      <th>Cellulare</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Antivirus</th>
      <th>Attivazione Effettiva</th>
      <th>Attivazione al cliente</th>
      <th>Scadenza Reale</th>
      <th>License code</th>
      <th>Licenza valida per n. pc</th>
      <th>Licenza attivata su n. pc</th>
      <th>Prezzo</th>
      <th>Opzioni</th>
      <th>Count Attivazioni</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @databases.each do |database| %>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" width="15%"><%= database.shop %></td>
<td align="center" width="5%"><%= database.customer %></td>
<td align="center" width="6%"><%= database.company %></td>
<td align="center" width="7%"><%= database.referer %></td>
<td align="center" width="10%"><%= database.phone %></td>
<td align="center" width="10%"><%= database.email %></td>
<td align="center" width="4%"><%= database.antivirus %></td>
<td align="center" width="7%"><%= database.activated_at %></td>
<td align="center" width="7%"><%= database.customer_activated_at %></td>
<td align="center" width="6%"><%= database.license_expires_at %></td>
<td align="center" width="16%"><%= database.license_code %></td>
<td align="center" width="4%"><%= database.license_activable_for_pc %></td>
<td align="center" width="4%"><%= database.license_activated_in %></td>
<td align="center" width="4%"><%= database.price %></td>
<td align="center" width="10%"><%= link_to 'Show', database %> | <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_database_path(database) %> |
  <%= link_to 'Destroy', database, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>

<td align="center" width="4%"><%= Database.select(:license_code).count %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

can someone help me ? :)
ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate value of `license_count`

```
class Database < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :duplicate_databases, -> {select(:license_code).group(:license_code).having("count(*) > 1")}
end
```

in controller

```
def action
  @duplicate_records =  Database.duplicate_databases
 end
```

In View

```
 <td> count activation:  <%= @duplicate_records.count %>  </td>
```

Comment: the variable where i've to put in the erb? >:

Answer (score 0):

Since you're new, let me detail some ideas for you!

--

**Language**

You have to appreciate "Rails" is *not* a language - it's a framework.
**Ruby** is the language, and indeed, [Rails is "just" a gem which runs on it](http://rubygems.org/gems/rails).

This means when you ask questions about the system, you will need to appreciate that Rails simply uses a series of components (such as `ActiveRecord` etc) to create a seamless & amazing framework for you to use.

As such, you'll want to consider the [MVC nature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) of Rails, meaning that you should keep any of the data-configuration logic in your controller. Your model should be there to build the data you need, and your view should just show what you need.

--

**Fix**

I would do the following:

```
#app/views/controller/index.html.erb
<th>Count Activation</th>
<td align="center" width="4%"><%= @duplicate_count %></td>

#app/controllers/controller.rb
class Controller < ApplicationController
   def index
      @duplicate_count = Database.duplicate_codes
   end
end

#app/models/database.rb
class Database < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :duplicate_codes, -> { select("license_code, count(license_code) as quantity").group(:license_code).having("quantity > 1") }
end
```

Comment: Hi Rich, and really thanks for be so kind :)
I've tried to do what you've tell me to do, but i got some error.


Can i show you (if is possible) in private my project so you can understand what i mean? is very important for me to understand how this work .. thanks alot in advice.

my index is now: like

Answer (score 0):

i've found a solution by the tips here:

in models

```
def dup_count
  Database.where(license_code: self.license_code).count
end
```

in my index

```
<td align="center"><%= database.dup_count %></td>
```

Thanks ;)